# 2nd player control doesn't work in ZNES 1.42 using netplay

Tags: emulation, windows, ubuntu, zsnes

Although the question is more technic- and not game-content-related I hope that someone here might help with this issue:

We are 2 players who tried to play a ROM over ZSNES 1.42 on two different machines using the Netplay Function.

We have no problems to connect our computers to each other using *netplay*, when he (Player #1) starts as a server and I (Player#2) connect to his computer as a client using his IP address.

We also got the game running on both our machines:

**Player#1 starts** the game and via *netplay* **Player#2 can** see the same screen as P#1 with audio, video and P#1's navigation on the screen. After starting the game in **2 Player Mode**, P#1 is able to navigate through game menus, move the character etc. but P#2 **can't move**, navigate or do anything inside the game using the keyboard settings that he configured.

P#2 will be able to pause the game, change his configs and restart the game again in the emu but input via **keyboard seems to be ignored for most in-game commands**. Sometimes, when the game is restarted one key might work for p#2, but all the others which were set in the P#2 input configs are still ignored.

**Here** are the specifications of our systems and which settings we already tried:

**Player#1**

- acts as netplay server
- Windows 7 - 32-bit
- ZSNES 1.42
- playing with Gamepad
- Config Input#1: Keyboard/Joystick
- COnfig Input#2: None (no key set for any control)

**Player#2**

- acts as netplay client
- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS or Windows 7 -32 bit
- ZSNES 1.42 (in Ubuntu and in Windows)
- playing with keyboard
- Config Input#1: None (no key set for any control)
- Config Input#2: Keyboard/Joystick

We first assumed that the differing OS of our machines would be a problem but running the game under Ubuntu or under Windows for P#2 results in the very same problem.

Comment: I've had this same problem, but you put a whole more effort into trying to solve it! Eagerly anticipating someone's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  Both players using Netplay should be configuring their Port 1.  Netplay will assume the config you want to use for your netplay session will be Port 1 no matter which player you end up being.